# rails 4 passing many variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a survey for my rails app which basically contains 3 types of questions , radio button ,check box and slide range. And there could be endless number of this questions

I am done with creating the survey , now when a user answer the questions

1st : how can i get all the answers he chose ?

2nd : how to pass all this variables to my `submit` method in the controller `new_survey` so that i can update the database with it , and is this the best way or should i do something else ?

here is my `show` page

```
<% for @question in @new_survey.questions %>
<li><%= h @question.content %></li>
<ul>
  <% for answer in @question.answers %>
    <li><%= radio_button_tag "poll", answer.content ,true%>
      <%= h answer.content %></li>
  <% end %>
  <% for pic_model in @question.pic_models %>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
        </input>
        <img src="<%= pic_model.pic_url %>" width="100" height="100" />
      </label>
    </li>
  <% end %>
  <% for range_slider in @question.range_sliders %>
    <input type="range" min="<%= range_slider.min %>" max="<%= range_slider.max %>" value="<%= range_slider.value %>" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
    <span id="range">0</span>
  <% end %>
  <% for rank in @question.ranks %>
    <li><%= h rank.content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

models:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :new_survey
has_many :ranks, dependent: :destroy
has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
has_many :pic_models, dependent: :destroy
has_many :range_sliders, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ranks, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pic_models, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :range_sliders, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

---

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :question
end
```

---

```
class NewSurvey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

---

the only controller i have is new_survey

```
lass NewSurveysController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_new_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
# GET /new_surveys
# GET /new_surveys.json
def index
  @new_surveys = NewSurvey.all
end

# GET /new_surveys/1
# GET /new_surveys/1.json
def show
end

def submit
end

# GET /new_surveys/new
def new
@new_survey = NewSurvey.new
end

# GET /new_surveys/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /new_surveys
# POST /new_surveys.json
def create
  @new_survey = NewSurvey.new(new_survey_params)
  respond_to do |format|
  if @new_survey.save
    format.html { redirect_to @new_survey, notice: 'New survey was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @new_survey }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @new_survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
# PATCH/PUT /new_surveys/1
# PATCH/PUT /new_surveys/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
  if @new_survey.update(new_survey_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @new_survey, notice: 'New survey was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @new_survey.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /new_surveys/1
# DELETE /new_surveys/1.json
def destroy
  @new_survey.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to new_surveys_url }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_new_survey
  @new_survey = NewSurvey.find(params[:id])
end
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def new_survey_params
  params.require(:new_survey).permit(:name, :user_id)
end
def new_survey_params
  params.require(:new_survey).permit(:name, :user_id, questions_attributes: [:content, :_destroy, answers_attributes: [:content, :_destroy], pic_models_attributes: [:pic_url, :_destroy], range_sliders_attributes: [:max, :min, :value, :_destroy], ranks_attributes: [:content, :_destroy]]) 
end
end
```

Comment: are you using a `for loop`? I haven't seen that used in Rails like that. post your controllers

Comment: are you using nested models? which show page is this? questions or answers?

Comment: i am using nested attributes , the controller is the basic one which is generated by scaffold , i updated my question with my models

Comment: I dont see why you need to go to `new_survey` controller since you are using `nested models`. the submit will go through the `questions controller` have you added all the nested attributes to `questions_params`?

Comment: Please post `QuestionsController`. I wanna see how you nested your attributes.

Comment: Questions is just a model that belongs to new_survey , i updated my Question

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, use `views/new_surveys/_form.html.erb` to create the nested objects:

This [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) should help you. it is about nested `survey, questions, and answers`. if you a railscasts subscriber, you can watch the [revised episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised).

on your first question: `how can i get all the answers he chose?`. that depends on how you nested your routes. if for example, you have your routes nested as

```
resources :users do
  resources :answers
end
```

Then you can go to `/users/:user_id/answers` to get all the answers of that particular user. 
This is `app/views/answers/index.html.erb`

Let me know if those `Railscasts` videos don't help.